# How to have both ReplaySubject and BehaviorSubject functionality

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have the following code:

```js
class MyClass {
  private readonly clientId$: ReplaySubject<string>;

  public get clientId(): Observable<string> {
    return this.clientId$;
  }

  constructor([... things]) {
    this.clientId$ = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
    
    someObservable
      .pipe(
        map(arg => {
          // business logic and what not...
        }))
      .subscribe(clientId => {
        this.clientId$.next(clientId);
      });
  }
}
```

I want to be able to use `myClassInstance.clientId.value();` e.g. like a behavior subject. In addition to new subscribers of `clientId` getting the old value since `someObservable` fires infrequently.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: why would you need it? your buffer size is 1 for replaysubject, which essentialy makes it similar to behaviourSubject.

Comment: Id like to have to ability to use it outside of rxjs, like a simple value.

Comment: can you not have another class variable and assign the latest value to in the subscribe block where you are emitting the clientId ?

Comment: I can. But there may be a better way to do it and maybe learn something new I guess.

Comment: The synchronous getter in `BehaviorSubject` is either `clientId.value` or `clientId.getValue()` not `clientId.value()`. And it is **only** available in `BehaviorSubject`. If you need that you could may be use default value `null` for the `BehaviorSubject` and not use it in the subscription.

Comment: Yes but I need the relaysubject functionality so new subscribers of `get clientId` get the latest value upon subscription. I think I tried behavior with shareReplay pipe but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: That's what a `BehaviorSubject` does. If you subscribe to a `BehaviorSubject` you get it's current (i.e. latest) value.

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't answer your question directly, I wanted to point out that you probably don't need a subject at all!

Subscribing to an observable, just to emit the value into your own subject is not usually necessary.

In your case, you don't need the ReplaySubject, you don't need the getter, and you don't need to subscribe in your constructor.

This should do the job:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(private someService:SomeService) { }

    clientId$ = this.someService.someObservable.pipe(
        map(val => val.clientId)
    );
}
```

As far as accessing the latest value... you *could* stash it in a local variable:

```
clientId$ = this.someService.someObservable.pipe(
    map(val => val.clientId),
    tap(clientId => this.clientId = clientId)
);
```

But often times that isn't necessary either.  If you're using the `async` pipe in your template, you get the unwrapped latest value already.

```
<h3 *ngIf="clientId$ | async as clientId">{{ clientId }}</h3>
```

Comment: There's a subtle but important difference: going through a subject multicasts the source, your way does not. If the source is expensive or not idempotent like a network request this becomes a big issue. Of course multicasting can be achieved through operators which hides the subject but still does use a subject.

Comment: I'm also not sure what part of the question makes you say that OP doesn't need the client ID to be replayed. There's many valid reasons to need that, no information on what they're looking to do with and and no information on whether the source is already replayed or not.

Comment: And lastly, your answer skips over the differences in error handling compared to the original solution, which can also play an important role. All in all the intention here is good but the answer is not nuanced enough to blindly recommend not using a subject.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out these differences. You're right it's important to be aware of mulicasting and error handling concerns and to use `share` or `shareReplay` operators when appropriate.  My intention wasn't to avoid using subjects altogether, it was really to point out something that I think isn't obvious to many rxjs newcomers, and that is: you don't **have** to use a Subject to push values "manually" though a stream.  It's often much simpler to transform an existing observable stream into the shape you need.

Comment: I agree, and especially with the fact that newcomers jump to this all too often, hence me saying the intention here is good (and in many ways I agree with you). My comments aren't exactly a deep dive into these questions but I hope they add some context to the answer for someone to consider. Cheers.